# selenium - chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

**Error message:**

> 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

I was trying to code a script using selenium in pycharm, however the error above occured. [I have already linked my selenium to pycharm as seen here (fresh and up to date)](https://gyazo.com/b5622e3165bbfd93cfa205178df79b6f).

I am new to selenium, isn't chromedriver in the folder "selenium."
If it isn't, where can I find it and add it to the path?

By the way, I tried typing "chromedriver" in cmd, however, it wasn't recognized as an internal or external command.

error shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sebastian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\sebastian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\sebastian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sebastian/PycharmProjects/web/bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/sebastian/desktop/selenium-3.0.1")
  File "C:\Users\sebastian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\sebastian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'selenium-3.0.1' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x01EDEAF0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sebastian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Users\sebastian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

Comment: what about the same error in MAC, how do you solve it?

Comment: @Awesome_girl Same procedure I suppose, only you now have to download the mac ChromeDriver version.

Comment: The executable must be under the C disk. If it's in the other disk, the file may not be found even if the variable is properly set up.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can download ChromeDriver here:
https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

Then you have multiple [options](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver):

- add it to your system `path`
- put it in the same directory as your python script
- specify the location directly via `executable_path`

  ```
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
  ```

Comment: Every browser has/needs its own driver, there is no IE on Linux or Safari on Windows. Selenium is just a tool which enables to you to "talk" to the browser.

Comment: A new error raised after I added chromedriver to the path.
Can you spot what the problem is?

Its something about, "permission denied." How do I give it permission?

Comment: Did you give the full path to the exe or just the path? You need the location of the exe file. If the problem persists search for the error message here, I am sure somebody encountered the same problem before.

Comment: I simply dropped it into my python folder. https://gyazo.com/04fcef5ee8ef8fa29ae9e16abfcb556f
I suppose that wasnt correct since it aint working?

Comment: try copying chromedriver.exe in your python script directory, it might be that you need to start the script as admin if it is located in a program directory.

Comment: I am sorry, but isnt that what I already did, copied it to the python directory?
As seen on the photo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127927/discussion-between-sebastian-and-maximilian-peters).

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing the same error message but can't seem to fix it. What can I do? Not that it helps much but this is the line of code I am currently using: driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='~ Misha$ /Users/Misha/chromedriver.exe')

Comment: @mkheifetz Your path looks malformed, try `executable_path='/Users/Misha/chromedriver.exe'` or check if the file exists with `os.path.exists()`

Comment: @MaximilianPeters that does not seem to work. I am doing this on a mac, would that change my code, and how if so?

Comment: @mkheifetz If you are using a Mac, the chromedriver files doesn't have a file extension, so it should be '/Users/Misha/chromedriver'. But try assigning it to a variable and then check if `os.path.exists(chromedriver_path)` returns `True`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have fixed that problem! However, when I execute my code trying to post 1000 questions from an excel file to a website, it gives me some gibberish output and goes to the website where it's supposed to put in the login and password to proceed, but instead if just keeps refreshing the page over and over again. Any idea why?

Comment: @mkheifetz: Please post it as new question and include a [MCVE].

Comment: I disagree.  You should use os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)) in front of your code

Comment: This solution is deprecated

Comment: As @Camillo mentioned specifying executable_path directly is now deprecated. You now need to import the Service class via:
`from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service` then
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(r'C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')`

Answer (score 70):

Try this :

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: I have run the above code. But I have faced with a new error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Thank you! I was actually in the process of making a repo to handle all OS's just like ChromeDriverManager and then found this.

Comment: Finally a solution that can be shared in a git repo, independant of os or arch.

Comment: `raise ValueError(f"There is no such driver by url {resp.url}")
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/113.0.5672.93/chromedriver_win32.zip`

Comment: For other people having issues with this; since Selinium 4.x it's slightly different. Please refer to the GitHub page of driver-manager for more info: https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py in get_latest_release_version(self)
     62             return determined_browser_version
     63         # Remove the build version (the last segment) from determined_browser_version for version < 113
---> 64         determined_browser_version = ".".join(determined_browser_version.split(".")[:3])
     65         latest_release_url = (
     66             self._latest_release_url

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split`

Answer (score 34):

Another way is download and unzip chromedriver and put 'chromedriver.exe' in C:\Python27\Scripts and then you need not to provide the path of driver, just

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome()
```

will work

Comment: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f3b0d9f3a10>> ignored

Comment: @Sohail, can you explain your comment more

Comment: fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
       fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
       fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
        # fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",getcwd())
       fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")
       self.browser= webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)It says OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error and sometime the above

Comment: @Sohail, can you ask it as a question and paste the link of that question, as the code is not readable in comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490692/selenium-firefox-driver-raise-exception-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error

Answer (score 14):

An answer from 2020. The following code solves this. A lot of people new to selenium seem to have to get past this step. 
Install the chromedriver and put it inside a folder on your desktop. Also make sure to put the selenium python project in the same folder as where the chrome driver is located.

Change USER_NAME and FOLDER in accordance to your computer.

**For Windows**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\FOLDER\chromedriver")
```

**For Linux/Mac**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/USER_NAME/FOLDER/chromedriver")
```

Comment: im going to throw in, having come across this while googling fthat for Windows, Chocolately has ChromeDriver which makes it easier to keep updated with simply commant: https://chocolatey.org/install  and then you can just use `choco install chromedriver`

Answer (score 9):

Do not include the '.exe' in your file path.

For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/to/folder/chromedriver')
```

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: `pip install webdriver-manager` in cmd/terminal first, then `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager` in python file, then as you said