# Selenium Firefox driver raise exception OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

```
def setUp(self):
   display = Xvfb()
   display.start()
   fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
   fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
   fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
   fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")
       self.browser= webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

On `webdriver.firefox` it raises an exception even I tried with geckodriver path

```
self.browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver',firefox_profile=fp)
```

But still it raises an exception

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fbCampaign.py", line 23, in setUp
    self.browser= webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver',firefox_profile=fp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

...means the **geckodriver** binary which you are trying to use was compiled for a different platform.

### Solution

Download the **GeckoDriver** binary specific to your platform (Windows, Mac, Linux) from [GeckoDriver Release Repository](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

You must choose the correct **GeckoDriver** binary to match the underlying OS it will be run on:

- `geckodriver-v0.22.0-linux32.tar.gz`: For Linux OS.
- `geckodriver-v0.22.0-macos.tar.gz`: For MAC OSX.
- `geckodriver-v0.22.0-win32.zip`: For Windows 32-bit OS.
- `geckodriver-v0.22.0-win64.zip`: For Windows 64-bit OS.

**Note**: Once you download you need to *unzip* / *untar* the *GeckoDriver* binary.