# I'm trying to use selenium but keep getting this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, getpass

I'm trying to make a python program that you can use as a module for instagram.com. Here's the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass

user = input("Enter your username/email: ")
pwd = getpass(prompt="Enter your password: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

usr_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_2hvTZ.pexuQ.zyHYP")
usr_box.send_keys(user)
```

After executing this I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\OneDrive\Desktop\Desktop\Python\Projects\Instagram Module.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: So *is* chromedriver on your path?

Comment: I ran the .exe but Im not sure how to add it to my path

Comment: Did you try searching for e.g. *"Windows add executable to path"*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40559996/2425654 will help you

Answer (score 0):

Either add the path to Chromedriver executable to your Windows PATH variable, or you can specify the path to the executable when creating the `WebDriver` object:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```

for example

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
```