# BeautifulSoup Number Extraction

Tags: python

``So im trying to get the degrees from this weather site. But i t keeps returning a blank answer. This is my code
[Link to a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLvBQ.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# -----------------------------get site info------------------------------- #


URL = "https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/hourly-weather-forecast/ontario/oakville"
request = requests.get(URL)
# print(request.content)

# ----------------------parse site info---------------- #

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html5lib')

#print(soup.prettify().encode("utf-8"))

weatherdata = soup.find('span', class_='temp')

print(weatherdata)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please copy/paste your code rather than attach a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that those values are rendered dynamically i.e. the values might be populated by javascript in the page.

`requests.get()` simply returns the markup received from the server without any further client-side changes so it's not fully about waiting.

You could perhaps use [Selenium Chrome Webdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) to load the page URL and get the page source. (Or you can use Firefox driver).

Go to `chrome://settings/help` check your current chrome version and download the driver for that version from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). Make sure to either keep the driver file in your `PATH` or the same folder where your python script is.

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/hourly-weather-forecast/ontario/oakville"

#Make it headless i.e. run in backgroud without opening chrome window
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# use Chrome to get page with javascript generated content
with Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options) as browser:
     browser.get(url)
     page_source = browser.page_source

#Parse the final page source
soup = bs(page_source, 'html.parser')

weatherdata = soup.find('span', class_='temp')

print(weatherdata.text)
```

```
10
```

References:

[Get page generated with Javascript in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960288/get-page-generated-with-javascript-in-python)

[selenium - chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555930/selenium-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path/40556092)

Comment: still doesnt return the value. Im looking for the temperature

Comment: @NoahHamilton, Glad it worked, could you please help accept the answer? :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be that the data is loaded via JavaScript so it takes a while to load the value for that specific span. When you do your request it seems to be empty and only loads in after a bit. One possible solution to this would be using selenium to wait for the page to load and then extract html afterwards.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/hourly-weather-forecast/ontario/oakville"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
elem = soup.find('span', class_='temp')

print(elem.text)
```