# Requests.get() function does not give same result as the webbrowser.open() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tableau-api

I have a url which I need to run in order for a refresh to happen. It will refresh the data cache and display the latest uploaded data in tableau server. The url is like this:

```
http://servername/views/workbookname/dashboard1?:refresh=yes
```

When I use the webbrowser library to open the url, the refresh is executed but I get a browser which is open. When I use requests to get the url, it does not refresh and gives me a Response of 200 which I assume is successful.

Anyone knows why it could happen? How can I silently use the webbrowser lib to open the url and close it afterwards or have the requests act as a webbrowser when doing the get function?

```
import webbrowser
url = 'http://servername/views/workbookname/dashboard1?:refresh=yes'
webbrowser.open(url)

import requests
url = "http://servername/views/workbookname/dashboard1?:refresh=yes"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
html = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(html)
```

Comment: What is your final goal here? Just to refresh the data? Or to do some work with it afterwards? If so, what kind of work? Depending on your goal, the implementation could be entirely different.

Comment: Try doing the request with a `requests.post` call instead.

Comment: @JackTaylor Yes just to simulate the run of the webpage with the ?:refresh=yes

Comment: @b_c I have tried this but it didn't work

Comment: Did the answer below work? If not, any errors?

Comment: @RithinChalumuri No, I have tried it multiple times. No errors, I get the html text when I print the page_source.

Comment: [This post](https://community.tableau.com/thread/226546) on the Tableau Community Forums suggests that you should use the API to issue the Refresh command directly instead of through the browser via code. They do have a [python library](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/) available that you can use (as opposed to JavaScript).

Comment: When you open your url, `webbrowser` module launches your default browser that has your credentials/cookies so it works. Whereas, if your url needs any authentication or login to access, you'll have provide these in selenium session. For example, when you try opening your URL from incognito mode or using a different browser in your machine, does it work?

Comment: @RithinChalumuri Yes my default browser is already logged in. If I run the url manually incognito, it will ask for login credentials.

Comment: That's the reason its not working. Every Selenium session is running with no cookies/data from your other browser sessions. If you wanted to go down this route with api. You'll have to first write code using selenium to enter your credentials in the browser and then call the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests.get()` simply returns the markup received from the server after 'GET' request without any further client-side execution.

Whereas in a browser context, there's a lot more that can be done on client-side javascript. I haven't looked at your page specifically, but there might be certain javascript code doing further processing.

Instead of `web browser` or `requests` you can use Selenium. You can read more about it [here](https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/).

Selenium lets you browser pages like you do use the browser but also gives you the flexibility to automate + control actions on page with python code.

You could perhaps use [Selenium Chrome Webdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) to load the page in the background. (Or you can use Firefox driver).

Go to `chrome://settings/help` check your current chrome version and download the driver for that version from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). Make sure to either keep the driver file in your `PATH` or the same folder where your python script is.

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "http://servername/views/workbookname/dashboard1?:refresh=yes"

#Make it headless i.e. run in backgroud without opening chrome window
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# use Chrome to get page with javascript generated content
with Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options) as browser:
     browser.get(url)
     page_source = browser.page_source
```

---

**Note**

When you open your URL, `webbrowser` module launches your default browser that already has your credentials/cookies cached. Whereas, if your URL needs any authentication or login to access, you'll have to provide these in when getting the page using selenium. Think of each selenium web driver session as an **incognito** session. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python)'s an example on how to simulate a login with web driver.

---

References:

[selenium - chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555930/selenium-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path/40556092)

Comment: I will look at the login

Comment: I have looked at the html tag it returns, yes it returns the login page. When I inspect the code in chrome, I can see the inner tags but on the return (print source page in python) it is not there? Have you ever encountered this? The username and password tag is inside the missing tag on the output.

Comment: @JonathanLam, I've encountered something similar in the past. But in my case, it was because the login form was hidden and I needed to first click the Login button and then I would see the email/password fields. If you know the ID of both fields you can set the values directly by executing javascript. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58737372/11914067

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your browser opens up is simply because that is what webbrowser.open() is supposed to do, instead of sending an HTTP Request it opens the browser and puts in the URL. A possible solution would be using selenium instead of webbrowser because when I looked at it I didnt find a headless option for the package you are using yet. So here it is:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "<URL>"

chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

with Chrome(options=chrome_options) as browser:
     browser.get(url)
```

In case this solution is not acceptable because you need to use webdriver instead of selenium you would need to find a way to pass options to your browser instance. I didnt find a way with dir() or help() to pass this argument to webbrowser but if I find something I will add it.