# How to put chromedriver executable in a path

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/project bitcoin/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/paulndam/Downloads/chromedriver 2/chromedriver 2.exe': 'C:/Users/paulndam/Downloads/chromedriver 2/chromedriver 2.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/project bitcoin/Browser Automation.py", line 3, in 
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/paulndam/Downloads/chromedriver 2/chromedriver 2.exe')
  File "/Applications/project bitcoin/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in **init**
    self.service.start()
  File "/Applications/project bitcoin/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver 2.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium - chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555930/selenium-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a Chrome web driver then you need to put the path of the ChromeDriver in the first parameter: `browser = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)` where `CHROMEDRIVER_PATH` is a variable containing the path.