# Chromedriver need to be in path but it's on the path What's wrong with me?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to build a bot but to begin I need to setup chrome driver but it's already setup in my path

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import fxhash.constants as const
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class Fxhash(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"/Users/alexandrejacqueline"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(Fxhash, self).__init__()

    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(const.BASE_URL)
```

the error is :

> os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Can somebody can help me ??
Best

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium - chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555930/selenium-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Comment: Nop work well on anaconda but not on pycharm

Comment: The point of the link was that you need to add the `chromedriver.exe` to your path.

Answer (score -1):

Try to select the chrome driver by its absolute path.

For Example:
driver-path=r„*/Users/user/chrome_driver.exe*“

Comment: i did but dont work :(

Comment: Work well on anaconda but not on pycharm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).